# Fancybox version 3 beta: How to use "index" to jump directly to a specific picture

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox for a simple gallery, with HTML like

```
<div class="item" href="0Showcase/Abstract/img/E75_2056.jpg" data-fancybox-group="button" title="">
```

Sometimes I need to show a picture directly based on a #number inthe URL for which I use the following code:

```
if (window.location.hash) { 
//    alert ('using index : '+parseInt(location.hash.substring(1)));
$.fancybox.open($(".item"), {index: 3});  // hardcoded for testing
};
```

This works fine in Version 2, but not in version 3 which will always show the first photo.  Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: well, that is the issue when working with betas. I guess you have to open a ticket at [GitHub](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues). It's not because `index` doesn't work but apparently `this.group.length` always returns `1` (the first image only) so no gallery. I would do this http://jsfiddle.net/XLK35/show/#1 as a workaround while the issue is fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I should have thought about that as a temp fix. I had reported this issue to the author already.